# Prove that $G$ is solvable group without using Burnside Theorem.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Let $G$ group of order $5^2q^m,\ m>1$, with $5\neq q$ and $q$ prime. We want to show that $G$ is solvable without using Burnside theorem. If $P\in \mathrm{Syl}_{q}(G)$ and $n_{q}=[G:N_{G}(P)]$ we have the following cases :
(i) If $n_{q}=1$ we have that $P\triangleleft G$, so the claim is true.
(ii) If $n_{q}=5$ or $25$ we have that $[G:N_{G}(P)]=5$ or $25$ we know that exist $N\triangleleft G$ with $N\subseteq N_{G}(P)$. If we prove that $N$ is not trivial, it's easy to prove the claim, but how can we do this?

If we can't solve the problem with this way, can you suggest me another to prove this claim?

Comment: Since $n_q \equiv 1 \bmod q$, we must have $q=2$ or $3$. The case $n_q=5$ is easy, and when $n_q=25$ you need to look at the image of $G$ in $S_{25}$.

Comment: If $q=3$ I think you can show that either the Sylow-$3$s all intersect non-trivially, or they intersect pairwise trivially. Doesn't seem to work so easily with $q=2$, but I'm not too fluent with this.

Comment: Thank you very much, i understood your hints.